# How do I abort "add a call" on iOS 13?

Tags: iphone, ios, phone.app

The scenario is I'm in the middle of a phone call, apparently my face brushed the button for "add a call". I'm still in my call, looking at that "Add a call / Contacts" menu.

I need to get back to the menus that let me switch between keypad and speakerphone controls.  **There is no exit/X/back out button on this screen**.  The only screen features are "Groups" and "+" (to add a contact) then it's a list of my contacts. Dragging down from the top does nothing. Going home and selecting phone app again simply brings me back here.

If I navigate the buttons on the bottom, I can get to a "Keypad", but this keypad does not have the button to let me switch to the menu with "speakerphone on/off".  Further, typing in this keypad Does NOT generate DTMF touch-tones to the recipient, and so it cannot control navigational menus.

How do I abort an "Add a call"?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a way out. You could add someone you know is safe to merge or won’t answer or just stay on the line until you can end the call.